# Excel tables with interactive dropdown menu

Tags: excel

I have several tables of 2 rows, it looks like this

```
Input    1   2   3   4

Ouput    2   4   6   8
```

I have also created a dropdown menu using combo box. Now I would like to link each of the tables to a specific item in the combo box, that when selected, this item would show linked table.

Comment: Hi Dodo! Please share what you have tried?

Comment: Well I was able to create a combobox with names of each table, but I can't connect the specific table to its name. I tried to follow a guide, which explained how to link a chart to its name in combobox, but I can't do the same for linking tables to their names.